# Passenger standalone works, but Passenger Module for Apache does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I have a RoR web app that I'm trying to serve up with Passenger on Apache. The weird thing is that I can access the web app if I use Passenger Standalone, but I can't seem to access the web app using Apache with the Passenger module.

The passenger module appears to be running as evidenced by the fact that I can start Apache with no errors and that Passenger-status returns the following:

```
----------- General information -----------
max      = 6
count    = 0
active   = 0
inactive = 0
Waiting on global queue: 0

----------- Application groups -----------
```

When I try to access the web app I get a listing of the public folder directory.

Here is my virtual hosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin smith@example.com

DocumentRoot /home/smith/www/dashboard/public
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /home/smith/www/dashboard/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I have the following at the end of my apache2.conf file:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger 3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11
   PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

I am pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. Would appreciate some help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After weeks of trial and error I have finally been able to fix this by RTFM. I am surprised that there were no responses to my question on Stackoverflow and I was not able to find any other articles elsewhere that helped with my question. This issue has to be affecting everyone who is deploying a RoR app using Capistrano on a Linux server running Apache2 and Passenger.

I have Capistrano deploying the app to /home/smith/www/dashboard which creates a current folder which symlinks to releases/

Passenger needs to find config/environment.rb to launch the Rails app. By default, Phusion Passenger assumes that the application’s root directory is the parent directory of the public directory.See: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerAppRoot

The problem is that when using Capistrano, by default it deploys the app to

/home/smith/www/dashboard/current/

So by default Passenger reckons the path to be:

/home/smith/www/dashboard/config/environment.rb

Passenger provides the ability to set the PassengerAppRoot configuration option in Apache virtual host file like so:

PassengerAppRoot /home/smith/www/dashboard/current

This allows Passenger to find the config/environment.rb file correctly:

PassengerAppRoot /home/scervera/www/dashboard/current/config/environment.rb

Here is the rest of my virtual host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com        
    DocumentRoot /home/smith/www/dashboard/current/public

   <Directory /home/smith/www/dashboard/current/public>
        Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride none
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
   </Directory>

    PassengerAppRoot /home/smith/www/dashboard/current

</VirtualHost>
```

There may be other ways to fix this, but I believe this is "by the book".

Comment: This is my exact problem and your solution seems like it should work for me, but it's not. I'm still getting the generic apache page.

Comment: Are you using Capistrano? What is the path to your public folder?

Comment: God bless you! I've spent two evenings trying to fix this error, I couldn't understand why it's not working, why nobody writes in tutorials that I have to point doc root to public folder of rails project...